# Interpret and display different Encodings for email bodies in ruby:

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding, html-email

I am using the [Email](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Body) gem in my rails app but I am encountering some problems with encoding:

I am working on a mail that presents itself this way:

```
....
Message-ID: <22D41F1A16CD5A5719309A96F8C95D50@vcrfnyjsz>
From: "=?utf-8?B?IOWFqOWbvealvOWHpOWFvOiBjOWwj+WnkOS/oeaBrw==?=" <info@nks-media.ru>
To: ...
...
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Priority: 5
X-MSMail-Priority: Low
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook Express 6.00.2900.5512
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2900.5512
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```

(I have omitted not inherent parts)

I fetch it with the Net::IMAP class of ruby an pass it as a string to the

```
Email.read_from_string
```

method of the gem.

It return me an object, call it `msg`. I now call msg.body and have this answer:

```
<Mail::Body:0x007f0045976ea8 @boundary=nil, @preamble=nil, @epilogue=nil, @charset="US-ASCII", @part_sort_order=["text/plain", "text/enriched", "text/html"], @parts=[], @raw_source="PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBIVE1MIDQuMCBUcmFuc2l0aW9uYWwv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\r\nRk9OVD48L0ZPTlQ+PC9CT0RZPjwvSFRNTD4NCg==\r\n\r\n\r\n", @encoding="base64">
```

so everything seems right.

I do:

```
msg.body.encoding # return "Base64"
```

and its right again, but here the strange, when I do:

```
msg.body.only_us_ascii? # return True
```

Should not this be false? The content type in the header of the email is 'utf-8'.
In fact, if I try to do

```
msg.body.decoded
```

here is:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">\r\n<HTML xmlns:o = \"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"><HEAD>\r\n<META content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=Content-Type>\r\n<META name=GENERATOR content=\"MSHTML 8.00.6001.23588\"></HEAD>\r\n<BODY bgColor=aqua>\r\n<P><FONT color=gray size=6>\xE5\x85\xA8\xE5\x9B\xBD\xE5\xB0\x8F\xE5\xA7\x90\xE4\xBF\xA1\xE6\x81\xAF\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE5\xAD\xA6\xE7\x94\x9F\xE5\xA6\xB9\xE4\xBF\xA1\xE6\x81\xAF\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE6\xA5\xBC\xE5\x87\xA4\xE5\x85\xBC\xE8\x81\x8C\xE5\xA5\xB3\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE8\x89\xAF\xE5\xAE\xB6\xE4\xBF\xA1\xE6\x81\xAF\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE5\x85\xBC\xE8\x81\x8C\xE4\xBF\xA1\xE6\x81\xAF\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE5\xA4\xA7\xE4\xBF\x9D\xE5\x81\xA5\xE4\xBF\xA1\xE6\x81\xAF</FONT></P>\r\n<P><FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00ffff\" color=#00ffff size=6><A \r\nhref=\"http://www.hnhn.club/xinxi.htm\">hthttp://www.hnhn.club/xinxi.htmhttp://www.hnhn.club/xinxi.htm</A></FONT></P>\r\n<P><FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00ffff\" color=#00ffff \r\nsize=6></FONT>&nbsp;</P>\r\n<P><FONT color=#808080 size=6><FONT size=6><FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: aqua\" \r\ncolor=aqua>\xE4\xBA\xBA\xE5\x8F\xAF\xE4\xBB\xA5\xE6\x8A\xA2\xE8\xB5\xB0\xE4\xBB\x96\xE5\x94\xAF\xE4\xB8\x80\xE6\x83\xB3\xE8\xA6\x81\xE7\x9A\x84\xE5\xA5\xB3\xE4\xBA\xBA\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE5\xA5\xB9\xE5\x8F\xAA\xE8\x83\xBD\xE5\xB1\x9E\xE4\xBA\x8E\xE4\xBB\x96\xE3\x80\x82</FONT></P>\r\n<P><FONT size=6><FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: aqua\" \r\ncolor=aqua>\xE3\x80\x80\xE3\x80\x80\xE6\x96\xB9\xE7\x93\xB7\xE9\x97\xAD\xE4\xB8\x8A\xE7\x9C\xBC\xE6\xB7\xB1\xE5\x90\xB8\xE4\xBA\x86\xE4\xB8\x80\xE5\x8F\xA3\xE6\xB0\x94\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE7\x84\xB6\xE5\x90\x8E\xE5\xB0\x86\xE5\xA5\xB9\xE7\x9A\x84\xE6\x95\xB4\xE4\xB8\xAA\xE8\x84\xB8\xE5\x9F\x8B\xE5\x9C\xA8\xE8\x83\xB8\xE5\x89\x8D\xE3\x80\x82\xE4\xBB\x96\xE8\x8E\xAB\xE6\x89\x8E\xE7\x89\xB9\xE7\x9A\x84\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE8\xBF\x99\xE4\xB8\xAA\xE5\xA6\x96\xE5\xAD\xBD\xEF\xBC\x81\xE7\x9B\xB4\xE6\x8E\xA5\xE9\x97\xB7\xE6\xAD\xBB\xE5\xBE\x97\xE4\xBA\x86\xEF\xBC\x81</FONT></P>\r\n<P><FONT size=6><FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: aqua\" \r\ncolor=aqua>        \xE6\xB8\x85\xE6\xBA\x9F\xE6\x88\x91\xE7\x9F\xA5\xE9\x81\x93\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE6\x98\xAF\xE9\x82\xA3\xE5\x8F\xAA\xE5\xAE\x9E\xE5\x8A\x9B\xE5\xB9\xB3\xE5\xB9\xB3\xE7\x9A\x84\xE8\x85\xBE\xE8\x9B\x87\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE7\xA9\x86\xE8\x8D\xBB\xE5\x8F\x88\xE6\x98\xAF\xE8\xB0\x81\xE5\x95\x8A\xEF\xBC\x9F\xE6\x98\xAF\xE4\xBB\x96\xE5\x90\x8E\xE6\x9D\xA5\xE6\x94\xB6\xE6\x9C\x8D\xE7\x9A\x84\xE5\xA6\x96\xE9\xAD\x94\xE5\x90\x97\xEF\xBC\x9F</FONT></P>\r\n<P><FONT size=6><FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: aqua\" \r\ncolor=aqua>    \xE5\x85\xAD\xE9\x81\x93\xE5\x98\xB4\xE8\xA7\x92\xE6\xB5\xAE\xE5\x87\xBA\xE4\xB8\x80\xE6\x8A\xB9\xE8\xAF\xA1\xE5\xBC\x82\xE9\x98\xB4\xE6\xA3\xAE\xE7\x9A\x84\xE7\xAC\x91\xE6\x84\x8F\xEF\xBC\x9A\xE2\x80\x9C\xE6\x8D\x85\xE7\xA0\xB4\xE5\xA4\xA9\xE3\x80\x82\xE2\x80\x9D</FONT></P>\r\n<P><FONT size=6><FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: aqua\" \r\ncolor=aqua>    \xE2\x80\x9C\xE9\x82\xA3\xE5\xA5\xB9\xE6\x80\x8E\xE4\xB9\x88\xE4\xBC\x9A\xE9\x94\x99\xE4\xBA\x86\xE9\x97\xA8\xEF\xBC\x9F\xE6\x97\xA2\xE7\x84\xB6\xE6\x9C\x89\xE4\xB8\x80\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE6\x88\x91\xE6\x80\x8E\xE4\xB9\x88\xE8\x83\xBD\xE4\xB8\x8D\xE8\xAE\xA4\xE4\xB8\xBA\xE8\xBF\x98\xE4\xBC\x9A\xE6\x9C\x89\xE4\xBA\x8C\xEF\xBC\x9F\xE5\xA6\x82\xE6\x9E\x9C\xE6\x88\x91\xE8\xAF\xB4\xE4\xBD\xA0\xE7\x8E\xB0\xE5\x9C\xA8\xE6\xAD\xA3\xE5\xA4\x84\xE4\xBA\x8E\xE5\xA4\xB4\xE8\x84\x91\xE6\xB7\xB7\xE4\xB9\xB1\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE6\x80\x9D\xE8\xB7\xAF\xE4\xB8\x8D\xE6\xB8\x85\xE7\x9A\x84\xE7\x8A\xB6\xE6\x80\x81\xE4\xB8\x8D\xE8\xBF\x87\xE5\x88\x86\xE5\x90\xA7\xEF\xBC\x9F\xE2\x80\x9D\xE5\xB9\xB4\xE8\xBD\xBB\xE6\xB0\x91\xE8\xAD\xA6\xE9\x97\xAE\xE7\x99\xBD\xE4\xB8\xBD\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE7\x99\xBD\xE4\xB8\xBD\xE7\x82\xB9\xE5\xA4\xB4\xE6\x89\xBF\xE8\xAE\xA4\xE3\x80\x82</FONT></P>\r\n<P><FONT size=6><FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: aqua\" \r\ncolor=aqua>    \xE6\x9E\x97\xE5\x8D\x97\xE6\x9C\xAC\xE5\xB0\xB1\xE6\x98\xAF\xE7\x9B\x97\xE7\x94\xA8\xE4\xBA\x86\xE5\x90\x8E\xE4\xBA\xBA\xE7\x9A\x84\xE7\x9F\xA5\xE8\xAF\x86\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE6\x89\x80\xE4\xBB\xA5\xE4\xB9\x9F\xE6\xB2\xA1\xE4\xBB\x80\xE4\xB9\x88\xE5\x8F\xAF\xE9\xAA\x84\xE5\x82\xB2\xE7\x9A\x84\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE4\xBE\xBF\xE7\xAC\x91\xE7\x9D\x80\xE4\xBB\xA4\xE4\xBC\x97\xE4\xBA\xBA\xE5\xB9\xB3\xE8\xBA\xAB\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE5\x8F\x88\xE5\xAF\xB9\xE9\xAD\x8F\xE5\xBE\x81\xE9\x97\xAE\xE9\x81\x93\xEF\xBC\x9A\xE2\x80\x9C\xE9\xAD\x8F\xE5\x8D\xBF\xE5\xAE\xB6\xE5\x9C\xA8\xE6\x9C\x9D\xE5\xA0\x82\xE4\xB9\x8B\xE4\xB8\x8A\xE4\xB8\x93\xE9\x97\xAE\xE6\xAD\xA4\xE4\xBA\x8B\xEF\xBC\x8C\xE6\x83\xB3\xE6\x9D\xA5\xE5\xBF\x85\xE6\x98\xAF\xE6\x9C\x89\xE4\xBB\x80\xE4\xB9\x88\xE6\xB7\xB1\xE6\x84\x8F\xE7\xBD\xA2\xEF\xBC\x9F\xE2\x80\x9D</FONT></P>\r\n<P><FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: aqua\" color=aqua \r\nsize=6>\xE3\x80\x80\xE3\x80\x80</FONT></P></FONT></FONT></FONT></FONT></FONT></FONT></FONT></BODY></HTML>\r\n"
```

Not utf-8 as I expected but ASCII-8BIT, and I don't know hot to use it, or see it in the browser.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's Base64, as revealed by `msg.body.encoding # return "Base64"`. I'm no email format expert, but I'd guess the Base64 nature of the body was revealed in some header you didn't include in your paste. (After all `msg.body.encoding` must be getting it from somewhere).

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME) isn't actually a *character encoding* like UTF-8. It's instead a conversion of binary data to ascii.

I think it's unfortunate that the Email gem doesn't take care of this for you.

But if what you have is Base64, you can decode it using the stdlib [Base64](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) class.

```
 data = Base64.decode(msg.body)
```

However, if it's Base64-encoded in the first place, what comes out the other side might not be plain text, but some kind of binary file format (an MS Word document? I dunno), so might still not make sense read directly even once decoded